# How to feed JSON data of coordinates to turf.polygon?

Tags: javascript, json, turfjs

How to feed JSON data of coordinates to turf.polygon?

**Example:** turf.polygon();

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[
 [-2.275543, 53.464547],
 [-2.275543, 53.489271],
 [-2.215118, 53.489271],
 [-2.215118, 53.464547],
 [-2.275543, 53.464547]
]], { name: 'poly1', population: 400});
```

**Example:** JSON form

```
var json = 
{
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": 
        {
         "type": "FeatureCollection",
         "features": [{
               "type": "Feature",
               "geometry": {
                   "type": "Polygon",
                   "coordinates": [[
                         [1.275543, 54.464547], // I want to feed these coordinates
                         [1.275543, 54.489271],
                         [1.215118, 54.489271],
                         [1.215118, 54.464547],
                         [1.275543, 54.464547]  
                    ]]
                }
            }]
       }
 }
```

**My pseudo code:** that doesn't work and returns an error message of `"LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions."`

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[ json.data.features[0].geometry.coordinates ]], { name: 'poly1', population: 400});
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `features` property is an *array*, not an object.

Comment: ops! I forgot to include that. But still same error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coordinates` property is already a deeply nested array:

```
"coordinates": [[
  [1.275543, 54.464547], // I want to feed these coordinates
  [1.275543, 54.489271],
  [1.215118, 54.489271],
  [1.215118, 54.464547],
  [1.275543, 54.464547]  
]]
```

When you do this:

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[
  json.data.features[0].geometry.coordinates
]], ...
```

it will resolve to:

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[
  [[
    [1.275543, 54.464547], // I want to feed these coordinates
    [1.275543, 54.489271],
    [1.215118, 54.489271],
    [1.215118, 54.464547],
    [1.275543, 54.464547]  
  ]]
]], ...
```

You want to extract and use the *original nested array itself*, without modifications. Try this:

```
var polygon = turf.polygon(json.data.features[0].geometry.coordinates, { name: 'poly1', population: 400});
```